# django FormWizard. using Javascript to hide/show form fields

Tags: javascript, django, django-formwizard

So using Formwizard, in one of my steps i need to give the option of entering 4 phone numbers. but with a button/clickable that says 'Add another phone number' and using javascript to hide/show those extra fields.. i cant find any examples of this. is it possible to do this with From wizard, and add javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin does that for you:

http://elo80ka.wordpress.com/2009/10/10/jquery-plugin-django-dynamic-formset/

The problem is that it will work on all steps in your formwizard. I have something like this to make it work for only one step:

```
<form action="" {% if wizard.steps.step1 == 2 %} id="phone"{% endif %} method="post">{% csrf_token %}

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
          $('#phone tbody tr').formset({
            prefix: '{{wizard.form.prefix}}'
                    });
                      })
</script>
```